# Need to choose an ecnryption method

Tags: encryption

I've got an homework to implement an encryption algorithm (I can choose what),

now we didn't learn about encryptions yet, I guess you can call it pre-class homework or

something, I know what is encryption in idea and read on how some encryptions algorithms

works, and I don't know which one will be good for me to implement,

at first I thought maybe trying to implement AES but I don't want to implement something

that I'll not fully understand what I'm doing, because as I said the encryption class

didn't even started yet and I don't know what for example is the RCON table or the S-BOX

Table, I know for what they're used but if I were to implement the algorithm it would

look to me like I'm just doing some byte actions with those tables without understanding

the true meaning of the values that lie in each and every index in those tables. (they're like magic numbers for me)

So I want a suggestions for something that will be a good for first implementation and easy to understand the concept of how it works, remember that I yet to learn about encryptions in class but we know the concept.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems too subjective for the site. However, I would recommend either the one time pad or a [classical cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_cipher).

Comment: I'd implement RC4. It is not too hard to understand and yet not as easy to break as something like a classical cipher.

Comment: @mikeazo yea I've looked up RC4 it's seems easy enough but some parts of it seems random to me, in the key schedule part j = (j+S[i]+key[i%keylen])%256, I can understand most of it, the key[i % keylen] is padding in-case that the key is shorter than 256 bytes, the % 256 is to ensure that j will be in the range of 0-255 when performing the swap, but why do we need the j = j + S[i] ? Is there a mathematical explanation to this or is it just to add some randomness ? Also same question regarding to the pseudo random generator part, anywhere I can find explanation for the not so obvious operations?